# Array in sas for Concatinating strings

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a data with name and strings,I want to add all the strings(col1,col2,etc..) into one column. 
The number of strings are not fixed they may be more or less sometimes. 
I can do this with catx but do not know how to achieve this with array.
Below is my data set.  Please Guide.

```
data a;    

    input name$  col1$ col2$ col3$ col4$;

DATALINES;
Harry abc dcd vgd bvd
peter cvc fgf ghg ghh
John fgg ftg uty gfdg
sheyala fgf jty fhf fgr
;
run;
```

here is my code:

```
data test;
length result $50;
set a;
result=Compress(catx(';',of col1-col4),'0D0A'x);
run;
```

But the number of strings are not fixed.

Thanks & Regards,
Sanjay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an array with an undetermined number of elements.  This assumes all your columns start with `col`.

```
data test;
length result $50;
set a;
array c[*] col:;

result = "";
do i=1 to dim(c);
    result = Compress(catx(';',result,c[i]),'0D0A'x);
end;
drop i;
run;
```

`col:` tells SAS that you want all variables starting with `col` and the `[*]` in the array tells SAS to define the number of elements itself.  Use the `dim()` function to get that number and loop over the values.

**EDIT:**

As noted in the comments, the follow approaches also work.

Without using arrays:

```
data test;
length result $50;
set a;

result = Compress(catx(';',of col:),'0D0A'x);

run;
```

Or if you still want the array:

```
data test;
length result $50;
set a;
array c[*] col:;

result = Compress(catx(';',of c[*]),'0D0A'x);
run;
```

Comment: An array isn't strictly necessary (although the OP mentioned it).  You could just put `col:` instead of `col1-col4` in the original code.

Comment: Or, if you are using an array for whatever reason, doesn't seem like you need to loop does it?  Just `catx(';', of c[*])`?

Comment: What is 0D0A'x in SAS?

Comment: @ Alph it is used to comress Carriage return